# Python: TCP packet queuing backlog

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am writing a script in Python 3.3 to receive sensor values from a piece of hardware and display them in Blender at a certain rate. This is happening over a TCP connection from my laptop to the control box of the sensors, which is acting as a TCP server and sending sensor values at 125 Hz.

The problem is that my scene update in Blender is set to a lower frequency (10-30Hz, i.e. 'film speed') which is required for performance and for preserving the animation frame rate.

The script connects just fine and receives values, however it fails after a short while and times out, and it seems to be receiving 'laggy' packets (i.e. data that is clearly not real-time, but rather behind).

It seems to me that - since the values are being sent at a much higher rate than they are being received - there is a growing backlog of messages which eventually makes the connection fail.

I've searched for a solution, but I am quite new to all of this so am not sure where to look. Any help would be very much appreciated and I can post sample code, though it's not much beyond fairly straight-forward TCP client examples!

A thought I had was to write a separate 'manager' script that would listen to the incoming values at 125Hz on one socket and update a set of global values, which another process would send over to my Blender script over a different socket, but I have no idea how to ensure it works safely...

Python 3.3, Blender 2.69, Windows 7 64-bit